# Restlet - redirecting to a resource

Tags: restlet

I'm trying to redirect `/boxes/{id}` to `/boxes/{id}/description` (Restlet 2.3.7):

```
Redirector redirector = new Redirector(getContext(),
        "/boxes/{id}/description",
        Redirector.MODE_CLIENT_SEE_OTHER);
router.attach("/boxes/{id}", redirector);
```

This seems to work except when deployed to a Servlet container under a non-root URL path. In that case, the base path is omitted from the `Location` header, and so the redirect does not work.

The book, "Restlet in Action," shows the Redirector working with an absolute URI. I'm aware that HTTP/1.1 does not allow redirecting to paths, but Restlet does create the rest of the URI for me in the Location header, except the Servlet root path part.

I have found [this old mailing list posting](http://osdir.com/ml/java.restlet/2007-12/msg00096.html), but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Comment: Have you considered using a standard `Filter` to do the redirection before the URL even hits the Restlet servlet?

Comment: try to add to both routs the same Resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new Resource to handle redirection:

```
public class BoxesResource extends ServerResource {

    public static class RedirectingResource extends ServerResource {
        @Get
        public Representation doGet() {
            final String id = (String) this.getRequest().
                    getAttributes().get("id");
            final Reference newRef = new Reference(
                    getRootRef().toString() + "/boxes/" + id + "/description");
            redirectSeeOther(newRef);
            return new EmptyRepresentation();
        }
    }

    @Get
    public Representation doGet() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Then I attached it in my Application's `createInboundRoot()`:

```
router.attach("/boxes/{id}", BoxesResource.RedirectingResource.class);
router.attach("/boxes/{id}/description", BoxesResource.class);
```